# countif outputting "true" or "false" rather than number vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to code a countif function into a loop, however, I am having a little trouble with the outputs.  Instead of reading a number when the computation occurs, the function keeps outputting "true" or "false".  Maybe there is an error in my code, but I have used many countif functions in the past without experiencing a problem such as this.  As you can see below, I tried to write the function in two different ways, but both either didn't work or outputted "true" or "false".

Please Help.

```
Sub CorrectSets()

Dim Cell As Range

Range("B100000").End(xlUp).Select
LastRow = ActiveCell.Row

For Each Cell In Range("S2:S" & LastRow)
    StartTime = Cell.Offset(0, -12)
    Shift = Cell.Offset(0, -14)
    SortedOp = Cell.Offset(0, -17)
    DOW = Cell.Offset(0, -5)
    'Cell.Value = CountIF(E2:E & LastRow, Shift, N2:N & LastRow ,DOW, B2:B & LastRow,SortedOp, G2:G & LastRow, " < " & StartTime)
    Cell.Value = "=CountIF(E2:E" & LastRow & ", " & Shift & ", N2:N" & LastRow & "," & DOW & ",     B2:B" & LastRow & "," & SortedOp & ", G2:G" & LastRow & ", " < " " & StartTime & ")"
Next Cell
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to be using the `COUNTIFS` function rather than the `COUNTIF` function given the number of arguments you're passing?

Comment: Yes, very dumb of me. Let me see if that helps.

Comment: @Gareth Unfortunately, still outputting "true" or "False"

Comment: @ksmit144 File -> Options -> Advanced -> *scroll all the way down to* Lotus Compatibility and uncheck any boxes (*note the last 2 sections are related to Lotus compatibility*)

Comment: Please post the output of the string you are using for the formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put a *countif()* **Formula** in Cell then:

```
Cell.Formula = "=CountIF(E2:E &...............
```

If you want to put the formula's **result** in Cell then:

```
Cell.Value = Application.Worksheetfunction.CountIF(E2:E &....................
```

Comment: There is also `Application.Evaluate("COUNTIFS(...)")` but I don't recommend it without specifying the worksheet names in the cell and cell range addresses.

Comment: @Jeeped ...I agree with you.....it is a lot of work getting the exact string for *Evaluate()*

Comment: @Gary's Student  I tried to change the formula to `Cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(E2:E" & LastRow & ", " = " " & Shift & ", N2:N" & LastRow & "," = " " & DOW & ", B2:B" & LastRow & "," = " " & SortedOp & ", G2:G" & LastRow & ", " < " " & StartTime & ")` but it is now saying that it is expecting parentheses where it shouldn't.

Comment: @Jeeped - if all ranges are on one sheet then you can use (e.g.) `Sheet1.Evaluate()` - that will evaluate in the context of `Sheet1`

Comment: @ksmit144 - If using `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs`, then you have to use `Range` objects as arguments, not simply `"E2:E"...` (plus, you forgot double quotes). See [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196714%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
Cell.Formula = "=CountIFs..."
```

or

```
Cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs...
```

See [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196714%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Plus:

1. To find the last row containing data in a column (B in this case) use

   ```
   Dim ws as Worksheet
   Set ws = ActiveSheet
   Dim LastRow as Long
   LastRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   ```

   `ws` is a reference to the Worksheet of interest (`ActiveSheet` in my example).
   See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920/2707864).
2. You'd rather fully qualify your ranges, and avoid using `Select` unless it is strictly needed.
   With the code posted above,

   ```
   Range("B100000").End(xlUp).Select
   ```

   might not be needed.
3. If using `Cell.Formula = "=CountIFs..."`, it might be convenient to use

   ```
   Dim frm as String
   frm = "=CountIFs..."
   Cell.Formula = frm
   ```

   for easier debugging.